# ext3 journal inode number

Tags: filesystems, ext3

I'm trying to understand more about the ext3 filesystem and was going through the source code when I had a doubt. Would it be possible to figure out the journal inode number for a given ext3 disk using any utility that is out there?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still interested this quote from [Ext4 wiki (you can find more interesting facts about ext-family there)](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Journal_.28jbd2.29):

> The journal inode is typically inode 8. The first 68 bytes of the
>   journal inode are replicated in the ext4 superblock. The journal
>   itself is normal (but hidden) file within the filesystem. The file
>   usually consumes an entire block group, though mke2fs tries to put it
>   in the middle of the disk.